# Disable mail check on login?

Tags: bash, login, email

When I login to console, e.g tty1, I usually see a message `No mail`, I know there's some program checking email on login, but I don't use that, how can I disable that command ?

I tried to grep from `/etc/profile.*` and `~/.bash*`, but nothing found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This message can also be provided by the `pam_mail` module, so you can just `grep pam_mail *` in `/etc/pam.d` and disable it there.

Answer (score 6):

Put `unset MAILCHECK` in `.bashrc`.

**UPDATE**

It seems, the above won't work consistently (although it won't hurt, and to some extent it seems to work). But, check out this section of `/etc/pam.d/login` - try comment out the last line (or, if it still doesn't work, track this further into the legacy file they mention).

```
# Prints the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login
# (replaces the MAIL_CHECK_ENAB option from login.defs).
#
# This also defines the MAIL environment variable. However, userdel
# also needs MAIL_DIR and MAIL_FILE variables in /etc/login.defs to
# make sure that removing a user also removes the user's mail spool
# file. See the comments in /etc/login.defs.
session optional pam_mail.so standard
```