# disable mail notification on login

Tags: debian, login

When I log in to my machine per ssh, the banner says: "no mail". Other times, it says "you have mail", even though I have no new mail. Obviously, I don't need to be informed about mail which I have already read. This information is completely useless. Can I disable it all together ?

I am using Debian Wheezy

Comment: Already answered, redirect to
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43365/disable-mail-check-on-login

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and change the line

```
# Print the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]
```

to

```
# Print the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login.
session    optional     nopen noenv
```

or uncomment the line completly.

See also `man 8 pam_mail`

Comment: @user55518 - what is the difference between uncommenting the line completely or just replacing `pam_mail.so` with `nopen` ?